How do I move a file from a different directory to my current directory?
For example, I'm in the directory main/projects/project_1/turned_in/ and I want to move markdown.md from main/work/ to my current directory.
How do I do that?

What's unclear? . is your current directory. If you mean move it from ../../../work/markdown.md then ... that.

Possible duplicate of How do I move one directory to another in Ubuntu

From the command line?
You can check you're already in main/projects/project_1/turned_in/ with pwd. If not,
cd main/projects/project_1/turned_in/ 

Then mv is the POSIX tool to moving a local file:
mv main/work/markdown.md ./

Notice how since we keep file's name, we only specify destination's dir. You can consult the manual page for more info by issuing man mv.

you can move your files easily from everywhere
mv path/to/origin path/to/destination

mv main/work/markdown.md main/projects/project_1/turned_in

